# Let $X:=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x_0,x_1\}$, where $x_0,x_1\in\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0,0\}$. Compute the fundamental Group of $\pi_1(X,(0,0))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X:=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x_0,x_1\}$, where $x_0,x_1\in\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0,0\}$. Compute the fundamental Group of $\pi_1(X,(0,0))$

What does mean ''compute'' ? i can only draw it.

or can we define a deformation retract in this case ?

Comment: How can you draw fundamental group? its is a group no? So you need to say which (actually familiar) group is the fundamental group of the given set.

Comment: A cylinder in $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: is it a group? what is a fundamental group?

Comment: Loops through zero which dont intersect $x_0$ and $x_1$

Comment: no. equivalence class of those loops under the relation homotopy. can you thing of some binary operation in which the equivalence classes form a group?

Comment: @GA316 a free group with two generators ?

Comment: can you say how you got it? I could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the space described can be deformation retracted on to a subspace which is a figure eight (wedge of two circles), containing $(0,0)$ at the wedge point. You should prove this statement (hint, the two circles making up the figure eight should each be loops around one of the removed points).

You should have met a theorem which says that, for sufficiently nice spaces, if $\pi_1(X,x)=G$ and $\pi_1(X',x')=G'$, then $$\pi_1(X\vee X',[x])\cong G\ast G'$$ which can be proved easily using Van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: Thats what i meant. Thanks